# How to fetch all the numerical values from cal command in unix with every week starting with sunday in row?

Tags: date, unix

How to fetch all the numerical values from cal command in unix with every week starting with sunday in row. It should fetch all the date values irrespective of number of days in current month, can someone plesase help?
example

```
  cal
 February 2015
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
```

This is my code so far:

```
Today=`date +%d`
Offset=`expr ${Today} / 7 + 3`
for Day in `cal | head -${Offset}|tail -1`; 
do 
    if [ $Day -lt 10 ]; 
    then 
        CHECK_DATE=`date +%Y-%m`-0${Day}; 
    else 
        CHECK_DATE=`date +%Y-%m`-${Day}; 
    fi; 
    echo Following are access details for date: ${CHECK_DATE};
```

So in other words, this for loop should have day from each week. I'm not able to get last week days to be precise.

output is coming exactly for first three weeks, example current week,o/p below

```
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-08
----
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-09
--
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-10
---
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-11
---
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-12
--
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-13
--
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-14
--
```

Output should be like this, for last week of this month, but is not coming for few months:

```
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-22
----
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-23
--
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-24
---
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-25
---
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-26
--
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-27
--
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-28
--
```

Comment: provide what exact format of output you want and what you tried so far

Comment: Hope you have understood my requirement after editing question details. Let me know if you still have doubts about question. Thanks.